# After wp_not_install() in wp-setting.php, script is not showing any result

Tags: php, wordpress, unix, cron

I am using a script as cron by including wp-config.php and wp-db.php files which suddenly stops working as cron, if I am calling that script from browser then it's working fine.

I debugged by using echo and found wp-config.php having some issue, after wp_not_installed(), system is not showing any result.

If I am commenting the require_once(' full path of wp-config.php') then it is further executing.

Need help to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I feel that you are doing things wrongly by including wp-config.php and wp-db.php files for cron.

Better way if you want to run cron job is `require_once(full path of wp-load.php)`

It will give you the full access to all the global variables and functions which you can use into your cron functionality.

Comment: Hi WisdmLabs, In Unix cron, which is written is php, I tried everything , but nothing worked, I put for echos and found that in wp-includes/load.php, there is wp_not_installed() function, script is not coming out from there